# How to find buildings damaged by disaster?

Tags: tropico-4

Playing Tropico 4 I experienced a tornado and four of my buildings were damaged. I found three just by hunting around, but could not find a fourth. Is there some way to list all damaged buildings, or any way to list buildings at all? I looked in the Almanac but there is nothing obvious there.

Comment: I don't think there is a way to highlight them easily. repairable buildings will have a yellow sign float above them, i think sometimes they change color to have a red shade over them

Comment: @DarylF yeah, that's how I found the others. It seems a bit weird that there is no way to list buildings at all. For example, to change immigration policy you must find a building on the map itself - this can't be done through a menu.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As I wrote in the comment there is no other way to highlight the damaged buildings except for the floating yellow signs above them.

From my own experience I have noticed some buildings don't have this sign but have a red/brown color to them, these operates at lower output and need to be repaired.

I think this could be a welcome upgrade to any new additions to series.